# When can we get other "Other StackExchange" options in Close Votes?

Tags: feature-request

We've discussed this at length, now that we've been out of beta for a while, are we going to get new options for the "This question belongs on another site in the stack.exchange.com network" close option?

We have Tech-Support as SuperUser but otherwise only Meta available. Would be really nice to have ux.stackexchange.com, www.stackoverflow.com, and maybe repeat superuser here for questions that aren't tech support but belong there.

When, or what is needed, for this to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communities get migration paths to other sites when they are required. They are required when it's becoming a significant amount of work for moderators to do it manually. Anyone with access to the 10k tools can see that [Graphic Design isn't there](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats). GDSE migrated 12 questions to UX in the last 90 days... and 25% of those migrations were rejected. And UX has the highest number of migrations from this site.

I just don't see the need here. It requires more touches to migrate something via the close menu - up to 5 close-voters, against one flagger and one moderator as it currently stands. Until the moderators of GDSE wave a "this is too much work for us!!" flag, we'll stick with the current system.

Comment: Should we instead have a Blatantly Off-Topic reason then? http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/should-we-have-a-blatantly-off-topic-close-reason

Comment: @Ryan I don't think it's either/or. If a question is good but belongs on another site, flag for migration. If it's not a good question and it's off topic, close it either as off topic or as whatever else makes it a bad question. If you guys need an extra close reason for that, sure, but it shouldn't be a substitute for flagging for migration.

Comment: @Ryan Moderators can create new close reasons, so I'll butt out and let the community decide on that question :)

Comment: Did you see Scott's answer on that question?

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason for that.  It is not polite to move questions for migration without first consulting other moderators from other stack sites.  We will ask if that question is in scope for them and if yes we then migrate it over.  This is why its not offered because we dont want to start piping bad questions or questions that are off-topic to another stack site.

If you feel it is a question that needs to be migrated please vote to do so or you are always welcome to ask me in chat or we can discuss it in chat and I can ask another the other site's mod if they want it.  Some questions are too broad to be migrated so all we can do to is request the OP to ask the question on another site with a little encouragement on what to add.

Comment: Wouldn't it take 4 or 5 user votes to even THINK about migrating though? And by that time mods have stepped in in most cases.

Comment: hey I got to throw down my size 13 somehow

Comment: I just see more options as making the Mod's job easier since which site would already be indicated by users and the one fell swoop of a mod vote would simply submit the close faster. But... you're the one all alone and doing the job of 3.... so your call :)

Comment: I see what you guys are saying but the biggest is quality than if its already a dup.  Stack gets a lot of InDesign questions but most of the ones I've been asked are already dups so if we just sent stuff over it would be adding more to another mods plate plus it serves no value if its sent over, then closed.

Comment: Migrations don't *need* to be pre-vetted, if the origin mods are familiar with what's on-topic on the target site and what a good question looks like. It sure is polite to check in, though, especially in cases of uncertainty.