# Flagging question for migration only shows meta.graphicdesign

Tags: feature-request

I was looking over the flagging options and I wanted to flag a question for being off topic. I noticed there was a flag as off topic and suggest migration option however it only shows `http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/`

[image: Off topic migration]

Is it possible to add more options here? Either a search for stacks, show most recently used or most used options.

Sites I think would be most likely used for migration:

- https://stackoverflow.com/
- https://superuser.com/
- https://video.stackexchange.com/
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [last time this was brought up](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1153/8708), we didn't really have a need for migration paths. The situation pretty much hasn't changed since then, we still have a very few migrations. Here's what the [migration stats](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) look like for the past 90 days:

[image: migration statistics]

A lot of the tech support questions we close are typically not worthy candidates of migration (low quality).

Answer (score 0):

Now that we're out of Beta I believe we can request such features but I'm not sure its necessary. We really don't get many questions for Migration except to SuperUser which is under the Tech Support close reason anyways.

Perhaps once we're able to migrate to 3D that'll be a common one but for right now I just don't know its very necessary. You can always just Flag it or come into chat and Ping one of the mods to take a look at it.

Comment: Yea, not sure how necessary this is, just was wondering why there wasn't more options.

Answer (score 0):

We really would need the migration paths to:

- *Stackoverflow* for those pesky programming questions

and offcourse the upcoming 3d site whatever its name is going to be

Comment: I agree, although *a lot* of the programming questions would just get closed or ignored on SO anyway.

Comment: @mods can we see if any more have been moved? I don't think we need one specifically for StackOverflow but I could be wrong. For the upcoming 3D site we definitely will need one for a while though

Comment: @ZachSaucier well often if there is something that i would need to send to stackowerflow i flag it as tech support.

Answer (score -1):

Just hit the Meta and let Mods sort it out :)

Comment: Mod abuse warning mod abuse

Comment: erm.. that was the consensus on what to do when this was originally brought up. Seems someone's on a down vote trend for me. Nice.

Comment: See here: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-cant-i-simply-vote-to-close-as-belonging-on-other-se-site-but-not-meta