# Why is Stack Overflow not one of the options under "close" > "off-topic" > "migration"?

Tags: support, close-reasons, migration

When closing a question why is meta.graphicdesign.com the only migration option?

Comment: See also [Flagging question for migration only shows meta.graphicdesign](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2676/52050)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see something other than Meta in that field, there would have to be a pre-defined migration path. These are rarely used, because:

- It would require that the close voters of the source site (here: Graphic Design) are sufficiently familiar with the rules and scope of the target site (here: Stack Overflow). I doubt that this holds in this case.
- It is only worth the effort if there is a considerable number of migrations happening on this route. So far, this is not the case for Graphic Design and Stack Overflow or any other site. Of course, this could change if more valid migration candidates would be flagged for migration.
- It often causes more problem than it solves as close voters don’t adhere to the [Golden Rule of Migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/255554).

If you want such a migration path, please create a feature request here on Meta and bring forward good arguments that it should exist – in particular considering the above.

---

Until then, if you are sure that a question is a good fit for Stack Overflow, either flag it for migration or close it with a custom close reason like:

> I am voting to close this question as it is not about graphic design, but about programming. It **may** be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), but please read [their guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking there, in particular about [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

For copying:

```
I am voting to close this question as it is not about graphic design, but about programming. It **may** be on-topic on [so], but please read [their guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking there, in particular about [MCVEs](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
```

Comment: I understand, thanks for the feedback. I happen to understand [so] but I imagine that's not the general case here.

Comment: @mayersdesign: Note that [the question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/95860/19174) which I presume to have inspired your request probably shouldn’t be migrated due to the Golden Rule.

Comment: Yes I see that now, and have reviewed the Golden Rule :)